# Invertibility of Units/Counits

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $\left \langle F,G,\eta ,\varepsilon  \right \rangle$ is an adjunction. It is easy to show that if $G$ is full, then $G\varepsilon  $ is invertible with inverse $\eta G$. But MacLane says that this is also true if $F$ is full. I do not see how this works though. I have an $\alpha :GFGa\rightarrow Ga$ s.t. $F\alpha = \varepsilon _{FGa}$ and then $\alpha \cdot \eta _{Ga} = id_{Ga}$ but do not see how to proceed from here.

edit: Following the kind hint given in the comments, the result follows by:

1). If $G$ is full, $G\varepsilon  $ is invertible

2). If $F$ is full, $F \eta $ is invertible (the proof of which is basically the math in the last sentence of the first paragraph).

3). $G\varepsilon  $ is invertible $\Leftrightarrow F \eta $ is. This is an easy application of the triangle identities.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. It's a typo in MacLane CWM p 90. He says: Given an adjunction $\left \langle F,G,\eta ,\varepsilon  \right \rangle$ with either $F$ or $G$ full, then $G\varepsilon $ is invertible with inverse $\eta G$

Comment: What? The word "either" doesn't seem to appear on the page at all.

Comment: @Zhen: It says exactly that: "...with either F or G full..." exercise 6, p 90, Ch IV section 3, CWM I do not know which edition it is. It's a pdf file. Also, I was able to prove invertibility only assuming fullness. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere. And isn't it true that if G is fully faithful, then the counit itself is invertible so what you say is obviously true.

Comment: That's on p. 92 in the second edition. I suppose you have the first edition. Anyway, the claim follows from the fact that $F \eta$ is invertible if and only if $G \epsilon$ is invertible. See [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+adjunction).